# Opening directories in Java

Tags: java

I would like to be able to open up directories using Java code, directory meaning a "folder" that contains a folder, which in turn contains files. This is the part of the code that I have now:

```
public void listFiles(String folder) {
    File directory = new File(folder);
    File[] contents = directory.listFiles();
    System.out.println(contents);
```

For some reason, if I point the folder to the directory level, it returns this line:

```
   [Ljava.io.File;@67d07b41
```

But if I point it one level down (at the folder level, which directly contains the files) then it will list out the file names in the folder just fine. Can someone give me pointers as to why this is not working for me?

Comment: What do you mean saying `open up`?

Comment: Can you post a runnable example that we can test? I don't understand the difference between folder level and directory level.

Comment: `new File(folder);` doesn't do anything except wrap the String with the folder's name.  What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: If by "open up", you mean list all of the contents, then all you need to do is declare `File[] contents = directory.listFiles();`

Comment: check the updated description, hopefully this will make more sense to you guys!

Comment: Have you tried using the Apache Commons FileUtils libraries?  http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html  I can't quite tell what you want to do, but I will bet that most of the major functionality has been done before and is included in Apache Commons.

Comment: you print any Array (String,Integer,etc.,) you will get the same output. since that is how toString() method is used in arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
public void listFiles(String folder){
File directory = new File(folder);
File[] contents = directory.listFiles();
for ( File f : contents) {
  System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

And you will see all full paths printed.

You're getting that weird output because you are printing an array object and that's what array objects will have as a `toString()`. If you want to print the **contents** of the array you have to do it manually as above.

Comment: thanks! now i just need to loop through those folders to get the actual file names